# How to get number of requests remaining from Quota of the day for my Profile-ID in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am Fetching Data from Google Analytics For Metrics (Pageviews,Unique pageviews, TimeonPAge, Exits) as below

```
 DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest r = GAS.Data.Ga.Get(profileID,startdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),enddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),"ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:timeOnPage,ga:exits");
 r.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath";
 r.Filters = "ga:pagePath=~ItemID=" + strPagePath + "*";
 r.MaxResults = 1000;
 GaData d = r.Fetch();`
```

I want to get a count of how many requests are remaining out of my current day's allocated quota for my ProfileID. Is there any method which gives count for the same??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to programmatically check what the status of your quota is. You can check some of the quotas project based ones on the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) but this is project based.   This isn't going to be your view based quota.

[image]

The best option is to count them yourself locally.  However note its not a perfect system Google sometimes lets you go over or under by a few hundred.